# Deleting checkbox items in a to do list

Tags: javascript

I have this simple to-do list that takes in some input and then underneath, it shows the text with a checkbox beside it. I am trying to figure out how to add a button to each item that deletes the item.

```js
function onReady() {
  const addToDoForm = document.getElementById('addToDoForm');
  const newToDoText = document.getElementById('newToDoText');
  const toDoList = document.getElementById('toDoList');

  addToDoForm.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let title = newToDoText.value;
    let newLi = document.createElement('li');
    let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    newLi.textContent = title;
    newLi.appendChild(checkbox);
    toDoList.appendChild(newLi);
    newToDoText.value = '';
  });
}

window.onload = function() {
  alert("The window has loaded!");
  onReady();
};
```

```html
<form id="addToDoForm">
  <label for="newToDoText">New To-Do:</label>
  <input type="text" id="newToDoText">
  <button type="submit">Add To-Do!</button>
</form>

<ul id="toDoList">

</ul>

<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"Any thoughts?"* - Questions that are opinion-based are off-topic for StackOverflow. Anyway, in the code shown you demonstrate a technique to create nested elements and bind event handlers, so use a version of that to create a button with a click handler...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have to create another element, in this case a button, and add a click handler to delete the parent element.

```
function onReady() {
  const addToDoForm = document.getElementById('addToDoForm');
  const newToDoText = document.getElementById('newToDoText');
  const toDoList = document.getElementById('toDoList');

  function onDelete(e) {
    e.target.parentElement.outerHTML = "";
  }

  addToDoForm.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let title = newToDoText.value;
    let newLi = document.createElement('li');
    let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    let del = document.createElement('button');
    del.textContent = "delete";
    del.onclick = onDelete;
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    newLi.textContent = title;
    newLi.appendChild(checkbox);
    newLi.appendChild(del);
    toDoList.appendChild(newLi);
    newToDoText.value = '';
  });
}

window.onload = function() {
  alert("The window has loaded!");
  onReady();
};
```

Comment: `e.target.parentElement.outerHTML = "";` -> `e.target.parentElement.remove();`

Comment: Thanks for your help! This worked amazing and when I tried to do it myself I was just over thinking it. This made it much more clear to me.